# Create new git repository from an existing folder tree

Tags: git

I've got C/C++ project that is composed of multi-level folder tree structure, and I'd like to store it inside local git repository.

using `git init` I create an empty git project, and now i'd like to add the entire directory tree, with an exception of non source code files (different from the following suffixes c/c++/h/hpp/sh/py/pl/etc).

Looking at other similar questions, I've used `git submodule update` but it didn't add the folder tree to my new and empty git project.

moreover, I know that in order to exclude files, I should use `.gitignore` file, but i'm not sure in each stage it should be created (what if the repository is already made, and i want to remove all .o files) 
Here are my commands, perhaps anyone can tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

```
[]$ git init .
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/myself/projects/otool/otool-ng-master/.git/
[]$ git submodule update --init --recursive
```

Comment: Create a .gitignore file before doing git add, and then remove it afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> using git init I create an empty git project, and now i'd like to add the entire directory tree

You have few options:

1. submodule - a standalone git project inside your root folder
2. ***`git sparse`*** - Checkout a specific (partial) part of your repo.
3. Checkout a specific folder/path

---

### ***`git submodule`***

***`Submodule`*** is a **standalone** git project so the code will be checked out to a **new folder** under the root folder and it's not part of your master branch.

Your root folder will contain a submodule file and you will have to "int && update" it on every clone you make.

```
# Add the desired submodule ot your code base
git submodule add <url>
```

You must run two commands:

```
git submodule init
```

to initialize your local configuration file, and

```
git submodule update
```

to fetch all the data from that project and check out the appropriate commit listed in your superproject:

So the full script is this:

```
git submodule add <url>
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

---

> moreover, I know that in order to exclude files

This is a very simple task: add the desired path/file whic yoiu wish to ignore to your `.gitignore` file

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is to do like this:

> cd your_project_root_folder
>
> git init

Then create a .gitignore file to ignore generated files (*.o, *.a, ...).

> git add .

This will add all your project files to the Git repository with the exception of the ignored ones. If files not intended for preservation are added to the repository then update your .gitignore file, then type:

> rm -fr .git
>
> git init
>
> git add .

When you are happy of your .gitignore file, just type:

> git commit -m "My first commit"

Answer (score 0):

Juste create a `.gitignore` file with a line to ignore `.o` files for example. Then add your folders to the index `git add *` and commit.

Comment: It does not answer the question - how to add subfolder to the project